# How to fill textboxes and optionbutton from ComboBox?

Tags: excel, vba

I need a code for this userform, when I choose some item from ComboBox to fill textboxes and optionbutton from my "Sheet1" table.

[image]

Comment: It's easy enough to accomplish, but you really need to post what code you've tried, and not just ask people to do your work for you.  Post what tactics you've tried already, maybe show some research on what you've already looked into and failed at, and ask some questions about how to overcome those problems..

Comment: HINT: You are going to need an event to handle when your combo box value changes.  Then in the code for that, look up the values you are trying to set by using the value you just got from your comboBox.  Do some research on that, try some coding for yourself.  Post it, and I will be happy to modify or help you through it.

Comment: ok sorry I'm new here, this is what I managed to type, I need only help with OptionButtons to set true or false if is male or female in the table.

Comment: I added an answer that addresses that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would do what you are trying to accomplish.  Just insert this wherever you are pulling the other data out.

```
If Sheets("SheetName").Cells(row, 5) = "Male" Then
    OptionButton1 = True
    OptionButton2 = False
ElseIf Sheets("SheetName").Cells(row, 5) = "Female" Then
    OptionButton1 = False    
    OptionButton2 = True
Else
    MsgBox("Sex not Male or Female")
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
This is the code for this userform:

Dim Project As Workbook
Dim SheeT As Worksheet
Dim Closing As Boolean

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

Set Project = Workbooks("Navi4.xlsm") ' ThisWorkbook
Set SheeT = Project.Worksheets("Sheet1")

With SheeT
    ComboBox1.List = .Range("C2", .Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value
End With

End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

Dim Item As Long

Item = ComboBox1.ListIndex

If Item = -1 Then
    Exit Sub    ' nothing selected
End If

TextBox1.Value = SheeT.Range("C" & Item + 2).Value
TextBox2.Value = SheeT.Range("D" & Item + 2).Value

If Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & Item + 2).Value = "Male" Then
    OptionButton1 = True
    OptionButton2 = False
ElseIf Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E" & Item + 2).Value = "Female" Then
    OptionButton1 = False
    OptionButton2 = True
Else
    MsgBox ("Sex not Male or Female")
End If

End Sub


Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer, CloseMode As Integer)

Closing = True

End Sub
```